# Error when using the Laravel Livewire wireui library

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I have the following library installed:
"wireui/wireui": "^1.17"

in my laravel and livewire project and in the layout file I have it defined as it appears in the documentation:

[image]

However, when I try to use the components I always get the same errors,
For example:

[image]

I really tried everything and I can't find the error.

Comment: The error is not observed in the publication but it is the following      cdn.min.js:5 Uncaught (in promise) {isFromCancelledTransition: true}
(anónimo) @ cdn.min.js:5
(anónimo) @ alpinejs.js?v=af1477d1:1113
(anónimo) @ alpinejs.js?v=af1477d1:889
transition @ alpinejs.js?v=af1477d1:1063
out @ alpinejs.js?v=af1477d1:1004
(anónimo) @ cdn.min.js:5
window.Element._x_toggleAndCascadeWithTransitions @ cdn.min.js:5